# How to exit a chroot inside a perl script?

Tags: linux, perl, chroot

While writing a perl script intended to fully automate the setup of virtual machines (Xen pv) I hit a small maybe very simple problem.

Using perl's [chroot function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chroot.html) I do my things on the guest file system and then I need to get back to my initial real root. How the hell I do that?

Script example:

```
`mount $disk_image $mount_point`;

chdir($mount_point);
chroot($mount_point);

#[Do my things...]

#<Exit chroot wanted here>

`umount $mount_point`;

#[Post install things...]
```

I've tried *exit;* but obviously that exit the whole script.

Searching for a way to exit the chroot I've found a number of scripts who aim to exit an **already** setup chroot (privilege escalation). Since I do the chroot here theses methods do not aplies.

Tried some crazy things like:

```
opendir REAL_ROOT, "/";
chdir($mount_point);
chroot($mount_point);
chdir(*REAL_ROOT);
```

But no go.

**UPDATE**
Some points to consider:

- I can't split the script in multiple files. (Silly reasons, but really, I can't)
- The chrooted part involve using a lot of data gathered earlier by the script (before the chroot), enforcing the need of not lunching another script inside the chroot.
- Using open, system or backticks is not good, I need to run commands and based on the output (not the exit code, the actual output) do other things.
- Steps after the chroot depends on what was done inside the chroot, hence I need to have all the variables I defined or changed while inside, outside.
- Fork is possible, but I don't know a good way to handle correctly the passing of informations from and to the child.

Comment: I think you need to fork chrooted part and wait for it's exit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The chrooted process() cannot "unchroot" itself by exiting (which would just exit).

You have to spawn a children process, which will chroot.

Something along the lines of the following should do the trick:

```
if (fork())
{
   # parent
   wait;
}
else
{
   # children
   chroot("/path/to/somewhere/");
   # do some Perl stuff inside the chroot...
   exit;  
}

# The parent can continue it's stuff after his chrooted children did some others stuff...
```

It stills lacks of some error checking thought.

Comment: Thanks to everybody that mentioned that this is impossible. And providing the fork solution.
Not as elegant as I expected but will do. Thanks for the example too.

Answer (score 4):

You can't undo a `chroot()` on a process - that's the whole point of the system call.

You need a second process (a child process) to do the work in the chrooted environment.  Fork, and have the child undergo the `chroot` and do its stuff and exit, leaving the parent to do the cleanup.

Answer (score 2):

Try spawning a child process that does the `chroot`, e.g. with `system` or `fork` depending on your needs, and waiting for the child to return the main program continues.

Comment: That's the first thing I did. But was too limited.
I need to run commands and get output of them.
Doing `open(CHROOT, "chroot '$mount_point' /bin/bash |");` is not read/write but only one or the other.

Comment: @Alexandre - Use `IPC::Open3` to do both reading and writing on an external command.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it might be promising:

[Breaking Out of a Chroot Jail Using PERL](http://pentestmonkey.net/blog/chroot-breakout-perl)

Comment: This page talk about exiting a chroot and lunching a shell out of it, that's privilege escalation. I've tried that but in my case it can't work. I need to unmount the drive on which the script is running, so I need it to be either killed or outside of the chroot.
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Save the original root as the current working directory or as a file descriptor:

```
chdir "/";
chroot "/mnt";
# Do something
chroot ".";
```

OR

```
open DIR, "<", "/";
chroot "/mnt";
# Do something
chdir DIR;
chroot ".";
close DIR;
```